# Redirect URLs from many subdomains using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns, subdomain

I am changing my website structure and I need to redirect 301 many URLs from many subdomains.
I have many subdomains, How can I do that in one .htaccess ?
Redirect both :

**ch.mydomain.com/coffee** to **www.mydomain.com/de_ch/coffee**

**it.mydomain.com/coffee** to **www,mydomain.com/it_IT/coffee**

EDIT : 
Some URLs have folder and some have different name :
exm :

**ch.mydomain.com/coffetype/nespresso** to **www.mydomain.com/de_ch/nespressocafe**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these redirect rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# specific rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ch\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^coffetype/nespresso/?$ http://example.com/de_ch/nespressocafe [L,NC,R=301]

# generic rules that have same URIs after redirect

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ch\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/de_ch%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^it\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/it_IT%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: you answer could fit if I have same page name, but sometimes it is different and sometimes with folder. So I need a rule then I will use : Redirect 301 xxx yyy

Comment: Keep specific rules at the top before generic rules. See my updated answer.